Can we say induced emf depends on the path considered?
In electrostatic field, the potential  difference between two imagined  points does not depend on shape of path traversed between the two points. It also does not depend whether or not any material wire is present on the imagined path or not.
Now, in case of electromagnetic induction by a time varying magnetic field in a region, can I say that we can associate value to induced emf between any two points over some arbitrary path? Since the induced emf between the ends of any imagined path also depends on path considered as varying  magnetic field produces non conservative electric field.
Another question: Can we conclude induced emf over any imagined path does not depend on whether there is some material wire present or not along the considered path ?


can I say that we can associate value to induced emf between any two points over some arbitrary path?

Yes.

Can we conclude induced emf over any imagined path does not depend on whether there is some material wire present or not along the considered path ?

It can depend on that, because the wire can change induced electric field. However, for a straight short wire, usually the effect of the wire is neglected, and we assume induced electric field in the wire is almost equal to that generated by other sources. Only if the wire is long, or curled into a coil or inductor, its induced electric field becomes important.
